# Resetting D3s transform attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

After creating some simulations I was going to remove the transforms on reset (where i can change the simulation).  That way the viewport is not looking in a stale location.

I was manually resetting it and it looked good but when i carried out either a drag or a zoom, it would jump back to its old location.  I noticed the issue was related to the d3.event.transform properties being maintained.  I was thinking that the best course of action would be to reset the properties back to x:0, y:0, scale: 1, but i didnt see much with regard to the transform attribute.

How do i reset this?

The closest i have been able to do would be akin to:

```
const mySvg; // Native element
const g = d3.select(mySvg).select(":first-child"); // pointing to g, where the transform attribute is applied.
g.attr("transform", "")
```

which reset it, just for a moment until a tick, or drag or zoom occured which it would snap back to d3.event.transform.   How is this resettable?

```
//  This is my zoomable behavior i inject in TS
applyZoomableBehavior(svgElement, containerElement) {
    const svg = d3.select(svgElement),
      container = d3.select(containerElement),
      zoomed = () => {
        const trans = d3.event.transform;
        container.attr('transform', `translate(${trans.x}, ${trans.y}) scale(${trans.k})`);
      },
      zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed);
    svg.call(zoom);
  }
```

Given that it looks like this is related to event handling, by the source: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#handling-events
I am under the impression that i could submit an event for transform, but I dont really see anything giving the right information.

My goal is that I am going to create a resetViewport function which does just this.

HTML:

```
<svg #svg>
  <g>
    <g *ngFor="let node of nodes"></g>
    <g *ngFor="let link of links"></g>
  </g>
</svg
```

Code:

```
resetViewport(svgElement){
  const g = d3.select(svgElement).select(":first-child");
  // `g` points to the outter g element, the child of svg.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to the problem would be involving `d3.zoomIdentity`

If i want to create this reset function, it would be defined simply as:

```
resetViewport(svgElement){
  const svg = d3.select(svgElement);//  svgElement is a nativeElement.

  // Need to update the current viewport.
  const g = svg.select(":first-child")
  g.attr('transform', 'translate(0,0) scale(1.0)');

  // The below resets the scale and positioning of the viewport for subsequent move / zoom calls.
  const zoom = d3.zoom();
  svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

So when the reset is called it uses the identity matrix to set the location.